# IIS installation error

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I have installed IIS on windows 7 home basic (http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7).

Though some of the options were missing.....

after installation when I tried to access IIS, I got following error:

```
HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.
```

Comment: What exactly are the options that you mentioned that are missing?

Comment: IIS Management Console under IIS was missing..when i tried Configuring in Windows 8 i did not face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

- What do you mean you're accessing iis?  Is it via a URL?
- A 404 error means the server hasn't found the file it's looking for?
- You may need to correctly configure a default page on the server (you may need to create a page 'default.htm', or 'default.aspx'
- you'll need to try adding the IIS management console:
- go to 'add/remove programs'
- select 'turn windows features on or off'
- click '+' next to 'Internet Information Services'
- exp[and 'web management tools'
- check 'iis management console'
- this will install the console
- try again, you may find that it works
- locate the console (right click 'Computer' on the Start menu, select 'manage', under 'Services and Application', click 'Internet Information Services (IIS) manager
- Under IIS, select 'Default Document'.  This will show you what documents IIS is looking for.
- Try creating a document at whatever location IIS is looking for (by default this is c:inetpub > wwwroot).  IIS probably uses the default file 'iisstart.htm' that's in the wwwroot directory when you browse to http://*localhost*, but you can try
- You may need to create a website in IIS first, using the management console that you've installed, and provide a default page.  Creating and setting up a website is a whole topic in itself

Comment: yes..URL..After insallation i tried accessing using htt://localhost/ as specified in http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/ but it shoots an error page.In windows 8 it was installed successfully..